# How to Override component in PWA Studio

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

I have created new project using

```
npx @magento/pwa-buildpack create-project ./projectname \
--name @magezilla/projectname \
--template venia-concept \
--backend-url https://127.0.0.1/projectname/
```

How can I override `packages/venia-ui/lib/components/Logo` in my project ?
I have added in `/projectname/src/components/Logo` and update logo but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

We put together a [simple tutorial](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-pwa-tutorial-how-to-override-venia-component/) of how to override Venia components to display simple custom content on your Magento PWA Studio site.

You can check out 2 examples:

- Sample 1: display a Masthead at the Main Top Content position on all pages of Magento PWA Studio site
- Sample 2: display a slideshow at the Main Top Content position on the homepage of Magento PWA Studio site.

We hope the tutorial can give you some hints to override any element on a PWA Studio site.